# Can I execute code from another file in a T4 .tt template for code generation?

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4

I'm using several T4 templates to generate several T4 files, and most of them share a lot of the same code, so naturally I would like to make a function out of it and put it in a different file that all of the T4 files could access.

However I can't seem to find a way, or google for a way to actually use code stored in another file.

Is this possible? and if so, is there a simple example of how to do so?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more of the scenario please, as the answer depends on how you're using T4, for example Asp.net view scaffolding vs basic transforms in your solution.

Comment: @GarethJ
The t4 files are looking up ID tables in SQL and generating a .cs file with enums that match the id talble.  Thank you for the help so far! =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your question, it sounds like you're just using T4 in a normal template file in your solution.
In this case, you can just use the `<#@ include #>` directive to pull in your shared code.  It is a raw text inclusion mechanism, akin to C/C++'s `#include`, so you can move as much or as little as you care to share into other files.

See docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx).

It's worth noting that, at present, the include directive does not work in ASP.Net view scaffolding templates.

If you want to share code with your regular C# project, that is possible, but you need to build the shared code into an assembly you can reference.  It's not possible to just use the `<#@ include #>` directive to pull in a `.cs` file directly as the directives don't nest inside control or class feature blocks.

You can reference a helper assembly containing your shared code using the `<#@ assembly #>` directive documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying `<#@ include file="test.cs" #>` but if I try to use a class from my test.cs file it says it cannot be found.

Comment: Ahh, you want to include regular C#, code, not specifically T4 fragments.  I'll revise my answer.