# Pass Value From T4 Template To Another

Tags: c#, t4, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a problem, i just need to pass a value from template file to another (T4), for example i need to pass controllername from Controller.cs.t4 to list.cs.t4 (MVC 5.1), or if there is away to get controller name into list.cs.t4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share a static class Helper ? , rethink your design to be more "stateless" ?

To share "running-code" please check this answer ["Can I execute code from another file in a T4 .tt template for code generation?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887407/1901532)

> If you want to share code with your regular C# project, that is possible, but you need to build the shared code into an assembly you can reference. It's not possible to just use the <#@ include #> directive to pull in a .cs file directly as the directives don't nest inside control or class feature blocks.
>   *'Quoted From the above Answer'*